# Microsoft C# .NET YARP 504 Gateway error and Failover

Tags: c#, api-gateway, failover, ms-yarp

I am using Microsoft C# .NET [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html) as an API gateway in front of ASP.NET Core Web API (latest version) with Swagger and Kestrel.
YARP is used for intern redirections to many microservices.

Questions:

1. I am facing 504 http API gateway error for requests that execute more than approx. 2 minutes from swagger UI. How do I set an increased timeout?

Ex: https://URL/swagger/index.html => Execute POST FUNCTION => YARP_API_GATEWAY => SERVICE_API_PORT

2. If an internal service destination (endpoint) is down for any reason, how do I configure "Failover" to another destination?

Ex. configuration:

```
   "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": [
      {
        "RouteId": "Service1",
        "ClusterId": "ServiceCluster1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/api/Action1/{**rest}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          { "RequestHeadersCopy": "true" },
          { "RequestHeaderOriginalHost": "true" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "RouteId": "Service2",
        "ClusterId": "ServiceCluster2",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/api/Action2/{**rest}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          { "RequestHeadersCopy": "true" },
          { "RequestHeaderOriginalHost": "true" }
        ]
      ],
    "Clusters": {
      "ServiceCluster1": {
        "Destinations": {
          "ServiceCluster1/destination1": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5001/"
          },
          "ServiceCluster1/destination2": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5002/"
          }
        }
      },
      "ServiceCluster2": {
        "Destinations": {
          "ServiceCluster2/destination1": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5003/"
          },
          "ServiceCluster2/destination2": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:5004/"
          }
        }
      },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used YARP but going from the docs it looks like:

1. Default timeout for an outgoing HTTP request is 100 seconds. You can set the timeout per cluster via setting the HttpMessageInvoker timeout, e.g. add the following to the cluster config within each cluster:

   ```
        "HttpRequest": {
            "ActivityTimeout": "00:05:00"
        },
   ```
2. You can use passive health checks to avoid destinations after a failed request (again, set at cluster level):

   ```
    "HealthCheck": {
      "Passive": {
        "Enabled": "true",
        "Policy": "TransportFailureRate",
        "ReactivationPeriod": "00:10:00"
      }
    },
   ```

For a faster response to the destination being down, you can configure regular [active health checks](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/dests-health-checks.html#active-health-checks).

Comment: Peter Wishart: I tried but all in vain. I am looking for a working sample that can be tested. It will really help.

Comment: @peter-wishart: Are you certain it is `"Timeout"` and not `"ActivityTimeout"`? See https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/http-client-config.html#httprequest

Comment: It was `Timeout` at the time of writing - looks like it was renamed to `ActivityTimeout` in 1.0.0-RC1

Comment: The sad thing is that it still doesn't seem to take effect. We have configured it for 5 minutes, verified that this is being loaded in configuration, but the requests themselves time out in the default of 100 seconds.

Comment: @RossPresser - did you ever get the bottom of this.  I am having the same problem.  I have set this activity timeout variable to 1 hour but it still times out with a cancellation exception after 100 seconds

Comment: @Al_B Not to my knowledge, no. I'm not on the developer team that actually raised the issue though; so it's possible they settled on a different technology and I wouldn't know.